# Hi im storing a entire document data in to a document and searching the document data to match boolean search i.e java and angular and (html or css)

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm storing an entire document data into a document and searching the document data to match boolean search i.e java and angular and (HTML or CSS). using query string  query in elastic search it returning the relevant documents also but I need the documents only matches the boolean query string

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "(java or elasticsearch) and spring",
            "default_field" : "author"
        }
    }
}

{
    "took": 92,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 0.030296518,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "ramesh",
                "_type": "books",
                "_id": "0",
                "_score": 0.030296518,
                "_source": {
                    "id": "0",
                    "title": null,
                    "author": "Java\n Angular\n React\n elasticsearch \nblocchain\njavascript\nspring boot\n\n",
                    "releaseDate": null
                }
            }'

            {
                "_index": "ramesh",
                "_type": "books",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.010253567,
                "_source": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "title": null,
                    "author": "Java angular react elasticsearch blocchain\n",
                    "releaseDate": null
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

** I require to get the documents which contain 'spring' and one from (java or elastic search)**

I don't want the relevant search results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with your query, only issue i see is that OR and AND words should be capital.

```
{
"query": {
    "query_string" : {
        "query" : "(java OR elasticsearch) AND spring",
        "default_field" : "author"
    }
}}
```